# Are there any differences between dollar assignment and native store methods in using svelte store?

Tags: typescript, forms, svelte, state-management, svelte-store

I am building a form in Sveltekit, with TypeScript. To manage the user input, I declared form state with Svelte store, and encapsulated these in some modules. Here is the code that manage inputs.

```html
// useFormInput.svelte
<script lang="ts" context="module">
  import {writable, get} from "svelte/store"
  type Form = {
    name: string, job: string, home: string, gender: string
  }
  export const useFormInput = () => {
    const form = writable<Form>({
      name: "", job: "", home: "", gender: ""
    })
    const onChange = <T extends string = keyof Form>(key: T, value: T extends keyof Form ? Form[T] : never) => {
      const _form = get(form)
      form.set({
        ..._form, [key]: value
      })
    }

    return {form, onChange}
  }
</script>

// useFormSubmit.svelte
<script lang="ts" context="module">
  import {writable} from "svelte/store"
  type Form = {
    name: string, job: string, home: string, gender: string
  }
  type Props = {
    form: Form
  }
  export const useFormSubmit = (props: Props) => {
    const isLoading = writable(false)
    const onSubmit = async () => {
      isLoading.set(true)
      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(null!)
        }, 3000)
      })
      console.log(props.form, "form submitted")
      isLoading.set(false)
    }

    return {onSubmit, isLoading}
  }
</script>
```

`useFormInput` returns a form store object, and a function to update store with the method `set`. `useFormSubmit` receives form value as parameter from store, and returns a function to trigger form submit.
When I submit form after filling form, console says there are no valid text in my form store, such as `{name: "", job: "", home: "", gender: ""}`. I could see the form I have filled are displayed correctly after using dollar assignment instead of `onChange`.

I have noticed dollar assignment uses `set` under the hood. Are there any differences that I don't know between dollar assignment and using method?

Project is here **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-pjrhn5?file=src%2Flib%2FForm.svelte)**

Comment: Just use regular `.ts` files for store functions. No point in putting that in a component file.

Answer (score 0):

For setting there is no real difference<sup>1</sup>.

The primary difference is getting values as that uses `subscribe` internally and makes sure to unsubscribe when the component is destroyed when using [`$`-syntax](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values).
For that reason one should use use that when possible.

Using `get` like this is usually a mistake, as it is not reactive. Most of the time one should create [`derived` stores](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store#derived) and use auto-subscriptions in the components that use them. You can also have a derived store return a function to make it callable.

<sub><sup>1</sup>There is one minor thing that comes to mind: Using `set` instead of `$` tricks dependency analysis and thus allows creating cyclic dependencies which would throw compilation errors otherwise.</sub>